# Class does not exist symfony 4

Tags: symfony

I am building a crud app using symfony 4. Here is the TodoController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;
 use App\Entity\Taskslist;
 use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
 use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
 use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

 class TodoController extends Controller{


/**

*   @Route("/",name="todo_list")


*/
public function listAction(){
   $todos=$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('App:Taskslist')->findAll();
    return $this->render('todo/index.html.twig',array('todos' => $todos));

}
/**

*   @Route("/todo/create",name="todo_create")


*/

public function createAction(Request $request){

    return $this->render('todo/create.html.twig');

}
/**

*   @Route("/todo/edit/{id}",name="todo_edit")


*/
public function editAction($id,Request $request){

    return $this->render('todo/edit.html.twig');

}
/**

*   @Route("/todo/details/{id}",name="todo_details")


*/

public function detailsAction($id){

    return $this->render('todo/details.html.twig');

}

 }
```

And here is the  entity:

```
<?php



use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Taskslist
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="taskslist")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Taskslist
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @var bool
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="status", type="boolean", nullable=false)
     */
    private $status;






/**
*@param  int $id
*@return Taskslist
*/

  public function setId($id){
        this->id=$id;
        return $this;
    }
    /**
    *@return int 
    */
    public function getId(){
        return $this->id;
    }
/**
*@param  string $title
*@return Taskslist
*/

  public function setTitle($title){
        this->title=$title;
        return $this;
    }
/**
     * @return string
*/
    public function getTitle(){
        return $this->title;
    }


    /**
*@param  string $description
*@return Taskslist
*/

  public function setDesc($description){
        this->description=$description;
        return $this;
    }
/**
     * @return string
*/
    public function getDesc(){
        return $this->description;
    }

/**
*@param  bool $status
*@return Taskslist
*/

  public function setStatus($status){
        this->status=$status;
        return $this;
    }
/**
     * @return string
*/
    public function getStatus(){
        return $this->status;
    }

}
```

I tried to use AppBundle instead of App but got an unknown alias error.
Actually I am getting the following error: Class 'App\Entity\Taskslist' does not exist.
I have followed many tutorials but they did not help me
Can you please help me ? Thanks in advance

Comment: How does your `composer.json` look like? How do you autoload your classes in it (section `autoload` in `composer.json`)?

Answer (score 2):

You need the namespace in your entity class. Add this at top after the php tag. Same way of you Controller:

```
namespace App\Entity;
```

Comment: I added this. now I have a different error :     The autoloader expected class "App\Controller\TodoController" to be defined in file "C:\wamp64\www\todolist\vendor\composer/../../src\Controller\TodoController.php". The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or namespace probably has a typo.

Comment: Are you working in dev mode? Go to .env and check APP_ENV. Anyway, for cleaning cache php bin/console cache:clear --no-warmup and after this php bin/console cache:warmup. You can add --env=prod at finish of both commands for cleaning the prod cache

Comment: I changed APP_ENV to prod and cleared the cache.The error persists:/

Comment: If you were working in dev mode is ok. Usually, you dont need to clean cache, but sometimes strange errors happens and you should do that php bin/console cache:clear --no-warmup and after this php bin/console cache:warmup. At this momento, I dont know what is your issue. Do you have permission in var/*?

Comment: I ran the chmod -R 777 var/log/

Comment: You need that in var/cache too